# Would this question be ok if it were not specific to one song?

Tags: discussion

I actually like this question:

[What is the best way to practice enter sandman solo?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/65666/what-is-the-best-way-to-practice-enter-sandman-solo)

And I think it's objectively answerable. I can see how it would be closed because it potentially only helps the asker, but I use the same process to learn all solos that I learn note-for-note, so I feel like that process would be helpful for anyone wanting to learn a solo note-for-note.

Would it work to edit it to be "how do I learn a solo note-for-note" and then reopen it?

Answer (score 2):

The way the question is currently worded, it's more soliciting practice methods for this specific solo like [you'd find on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+play+enter+sandman+solo).
Edits can be an option, but with the post being as small as it is will drastically changes what the original post beyond recognition and the final result may not be what the OP wants.

I do agree the question you're suggesting is on topic an very useful for the site and the OP. The best course of action is to create a canonical question "How do I learn a solo note-for-note?" and ask and answer it yourself similar to the suggestions. This is similar to the suggestions when dealing with the "vocal type" questions.